# Firebase Android Reset password error

Tags: android, xml, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is a screenshot of the UI:

[image: Screenshot]

I don't know what the problem is with the code. I'm just trying to send a reset password email to the user's email. If you want you can take a look at the full code [here](https://pastebin.com/AE9qqucw). Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance! :D

Code:

```
    public void PassResetViaEmail(View view)
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Settings.this);
    alertdialog.setTitle("Reset password");
    alertdialog.setMessage("Enter email below");

    input = new EditText(this);
    email = input.getText().toString().trim();
    alertdialog.setView(input);


    alertdialog.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            ResetEmailSender();
        }
    });
    alertdialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertdialog.show();
}

public void ResetEmailSender()
{
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "We have sent you instructions to reset your password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(Settings.this, "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Error:

```
                                                                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac.zzdr(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(Unknown Source)
                                                                      at com.safariagaming.flix.Settings.ResetEmailSender(Settings.java:107)
                                                                      at com.safariagaming.flix.Settings$2.onClick(Settings.java:92)
                                                                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:161)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I know, but the thing is that is impossible since I typed in an email.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

> the thing is that is impossible since I typed in an email

Perhaps you did, but that makes no difference as you got this pretty odd code:

```
input = new EditText(this);
email = input.getText().toString().trim();
```

It makes no sense to create `EditText` and read from it immediately. It will not give you anything but empty string every single time as it is not yet even shown. You should consider reading it once dialog is dismissed instead.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please [accept it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)